# Can't import namespace from separate file

Tags: c#, oop, namespaces

I'm having a problem with the structure of my project. When i create a namespace in a separate file, but in the same folder test, from the program.cs file and try to compile using such namespace i get the error message cs0246: "The type or namespace name `test' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Here's an example of my created class:

```
namespace test{
  public class planet{
    public int radius;
  }
}
```

And here's my program.cs

```
using test;
class program{
  public static void Main(string[] args){
    planet mars = new planet();
    mars.radius = 5;
    System.Console.WriteLine(mars.radius);
    }
}
```

Note :- **compiling only program.cs**

Comment: You didn't mention how you compile this ... if you only compile `program.cs` then compiler knows nothing about other files ... use project file or command line compiler with both files

Comment: I was compiling only program.cs, thanks a lot. I still have to learn how to develop a project file but compiling both in command line did solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use project file or command line compiler with both files.

for this you can use visual studio or command line
By Project

```
msbuild.exe MyProj.proj /property:Configuration=Debug
```

By command line

Compiles all the C# files in the current directory with optimizations enabled and defines the DEBUG symbol. The output is File2.exe:

```
csc -define:DEBUG -optimize -out:File2.exe *.cs
```

Compiles all the C# files in the current directory producing a debug version of File2.dll. No logo and no warnings are displayed:

```
csc -target:library -out:File2.dll -warn:0 -nologo -debug *.cs
```

Compiles all the C# files in the current directory to Something.xyz (a DLL):

```
csc -target:library -out:Something.xyz *.cs
```

[For more detail refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543283/manually-compile-complete-c-sharp-project-with-multiple-files-libraries)